# Storyboard scene is not displating properly

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, storyboard, xcode5.1

I have 2 storyboards, one for iPhone and other one iPad. In my app I encounter a problem with a new scene that I've added. New scene is Table View Controller and I am not coding anything, all the information that table needs is created in scene, no coding involved (it's suppose to be for informational purposes only), just to display information and you can't do anything with it. Now when I open a scene on iPhone it works fine, all information are there, but when I open it in iPad, Table View opens, but it doesn't display any information that I've created. Does anybody know why is this happening?

Comment: Your problem is right there "I am not coding anything". How do you fill values in your table if you didn't write any code to support your table?

Comment: I writing values directly in scene, there is no need for coding, I just need to show the table. I have 12 cells each sell has picture and small title and that's it, there is no need for coding where I can put everything there and just open the scene. And it works for iPhone, but not for iPad

Comment: SOLVED, issue was that on iPad scene I didn't setup cells to static, they were dynamic so it was looking for code

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that I forgot to define cells as static in iPad scene, they were dynamic thus app was looking for a code.